# Getting reference to separate bundle in code

Tags: iphone, xcode, xib, nsbundle

We are using the below code to get reference to the bundle we add for our resources like xib and images however I am not sure what would be the code to access them in swift.

```
NSString *resourceBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DTPinLockController" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath];
```

Can anyone convert this to swift 1.2 code?

Comment: Why can't you do it?

Comment: I mean I dont have the swift equivalent code. I want to access a xib from that. I was able to do it in objective c

Comment: Another thing is NSBundle.bundleWithPath method is not available

Comment: You haven't read anything about Swift have you?

Comment: Yes, I have read however I have not gone through these things

Answer (score 0):

Constructors in Swift are a little different than Objective-C. Try this:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DTPinLockController", ofType: "bundle")!
let bundle = NSBundle(path: path)
```

And for loading a `UIViewController` afterwards in a NIB inside that bundle:

```
let controller = UIViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: bundle) as! MyViewController
```

Take a look at the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/) for the full reference. There's a selector at top that lets you switch between Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: var bunPath:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mybundle", ofType: "bundle")!
let bundle = NSBundle(path: bunPath)
bundle!.loadNibNamed("MyViewController", owner: self, options: nil)

Its showing nil value why so

Comment: That's probably because there's no nib named `MyViewController.nib` in `myBundle.bundle` bundle in the main application bundle.

Comment: Added sample for loading `UIViewController` from NIB

Comment: There is a xib named MyViewController in the mybundle.bundle and its included in the copy bundle resources too

Comment: @redent84...there is a image in the bundle, I can access that image by my bundle.bundle/youtube.png in storyboard. How can I not access the xib file

Comment: Can you provide a sample project reproducing the issue? It works fine for me